# Como posso fazer o usuário digitar um número inteiro positivo e exibir a soma de seus digitos exemplo : 505 = 5+0+5 =10

Tags: javascript, node.js

let soma
let num1

num1 = prompt("Digite um número positivo")
if(num1 < 0){
console.log("Erro você tentou fazer uma conta com número negativo")
}
else if  (num1 > 0){

}

Comment: Use sucessivamente o operador %, resto da divisão ou módulo, juntamente com divisão (Math.floor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

João, como o [resultado do *prompt*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/window/prompt) é uma cadeia de caracteres (um texto), você pode usar [expressões regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) para obter os números presentes. A [classe de caractere "dígito"](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes) representa todos os 10 dígitos numéricos.

Para que essa expressão regular funcione da forma desejada, você precisa incluir a [*flag*](https://javascript.info/regexp-introduction#flags) "**g**", pois "com este sinalizador, a pesquisa procura por todas as correspondências, já que, sem ela, apenas a primeira correspondência é retornada" (extraído do link sobre *flag*). Além disso, não usaremos nenhum [quantificador](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#quantifiers), já que o objetivo é obter cada número individualmente.

Entendido isso, podemos aplicar a expressão regular na entrada utilizando o método [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), que resulta em [um vetor](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

```js
let entrada = prompt("Digite um número positivo");

if (entrada < 0) {
    console.error("Você tentou fazer uma conta com número negativo")
} else {
    let numeros = entrada.match(/\d/g);
    console.log(numeros);
}
```

Com o vetor contendo os números digitados, podemos percorrê-lo para somar cada número presente.

```js
let entrada = prompt("Digite um número positivo");

if (entrada < 0) {
  console.error("Você tentou fazer uma conta com número negativo")
} else {
  let numeros = entrada.match(/\d/g);
  let soma = 0;
  
  for(let numero of numeros) {
    soma += parseInt(numero);
  }
  
  alert("A soma é igual a " + soma);
}
```

Perceba que usamos a [função parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), pois os números digitados são obtidos como [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). Em seguida, exibimos um alerta com o resultado do somatório.